# How to edit Qt tree node via dialog?

Tags: qt, tree, model-view

I build a tree with Qt, double click a node in the tree, a dialog pops up, edit it and then click okay. Will the tree automatically show the changes, such as the changed display (role) name on the node? Or do I need some "repaint" methods to do it? And how to set the flag? can it not be editable since I edit it via dialog other than (F2) renaming? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you bringing up the dialog on double click? If so how?

Comment: I think it can be implemented by just using mouseDoubleClickEvent on tree view.